# Assigning a variable on each line in a quick awk command

Tags: awk

Awk is awesome of text manipulation, but a little opaque to me.  I would like to run an awk command that boils down to something like this

```
awk '{$x = ($3 > 0 ? 1 : -1); print $1*$x "\t" $2*$x}' file
```

I want to assign `$x` on each line, i.e. not using the `-v` option, and then use it inside my print statement.  Unforunately, after the `;` awk has forgotten the values of `$1` and `$2`.  And putting the assignment outside the braces doesn't seem to work either.  How does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWK doesn't use dollar signs on its variables:

```
awk '{x = ($3 > 0 ? 1 : -1); print $1*x "\t" $2*x}' file
```

In your version you're assigning a 1 or -1 to $0 (the entire input line) since `x==0` (effectively) when the first line of the input file is read. That's why `$1` and `$2` seem to be "forgotten".